# Problems detecting camera poses in Unreal Engine 4.27

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I need to be able to detect the poses of the cameras (65) that are in an Unreal scene. I am using Unreal Engine 4.27.2 and unrealcv 0.4.0 python library, I found a plugin called UnrealCV but it is for Unreal version 4.16 and when I run my code I get the following error:

```
ERROR:__init__:205:Can not connect to ('localhost', 9000) 
ERROR:__init__:206:Error [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión
ERROR:__init__:153:Fail to send message, client is not connected
```

I think the error is due to the fact that I need the UnrealCV plugin for the Unreal Engine 4.27 version, since this plugin creates in the game binary the server to which the commands are then sent from some application as a client, for example the following code:

```
from unrealcv import client

client.connect()       
print(client.request('vget /unrealcv/status'))
```

Comment: "fact that I need the UnrealCV plugin for the Unreal Engine 4.27"  I would suggest that you either use `UE 4.16`, or contact the development team and request an update.  Either way, this question is not appropriate here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, It asks the community to update an existing software package to accommodate a newer version. This is not a coding service.

Comment: @Strom Thanks for replying, but I don't agree with your suggestion, this is a community open to everything! I have an error and I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: I commend your optimism, but the solution to your issue would be to adapt the source code to the latest version.  Due to the closed sourced nature of the Unreal Engine Source code, your request is not possible without rewriting the plugin to match the current version of the engine.